# failed to generate APK after changing the package name

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

I have brought a app template from codecanyon & change the package name using android studio. Before packange name change APK build was successfull, now I have changed the package name to`com.avantguardvpn.unlimited.freevpn.best.proxyvpn` & tried to build APK but it gives me these errors.

Task :app:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED

e: E:\PrivateVPN\app\src\main\java\com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\fragments\HomeFragment.kt: (164, 15): Unresolved reference: id

e: E:\PrivateVPN\app\src\main\java\com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\screen\PaidServerScreen.kt: (124, 70): Unresolved reference: color

e: E:\PrivateVPN\app\src\main\java\com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\screen\PaidServerScreen.kt: (126, 37): Unresolved reference: drawable

e: E:\PrivateVPN\app\src\main\java\com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\screen\PaidServerScreen.kt: (267, 59): Unresolved reference: string

e: E:\PrivateVPN\app\src\main\java\com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\screen\PaidServerScreen.kt: (305, 32): Unresolved reference: layout

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting errors in the `import` statements in the files that are mentioned.

I will assume the original package name to be `com.example.proxyvpn`. The `import` statements for the `R` package in the files will be:

```
import com.example.proxyvpn.R
```

Now, if you change your package name to be `com.avantguardvpn.unlimited.freevpn.best.proxyvpn` then imports for the `R` package will have to be changed to:

```
import com.avantguardvpn.unlimited.freevpn.best.proxyvpn.R
```

So change your `import` statements in the following files:

```
com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\fragments\HomeFragment.kt
com\avantguardvpn\unlimited\freevpn\best\proxyvpn\view\screen\PaidServerScreen.kt
```

Comment: Hi, I wanted to express my gratitude for your answer and helpful response. Your answer has been incredibly valuable, and it has resolved my issue perfectly. Thank you for taking the time to assist me. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks. Please set this as the correct answer in that case.